# How to ignore required field in form in Entity Framework, MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I would like to ask if its possible to ignore required field in form. Problem is i have complex form in MVC using entity framework where i want to create insurance and bind to that insurance only firm or person, not both. When i leave for example form for Person empty, it always shout out that PersonRodneCislo is required field.

**Firm table** and **Person table** are in 1...N relationship to **Insurance table**, coz person can have multiple insurances same as firm, but it cannot be opposite side.

For table Firm primary key is Ico
For table Person primary key is PersonRodneCislo
For table Insurance primary key is InsuranceNumber

so in my database model Insurance table has 2 foreign keys (Ico and PersonRodneCislo)

I tried use IsNullOrWhiteSpace method but problem is that it wont even reach to my create method so i have to force EF somehow to ignore one of those two field if one of them is filled

Code for [POST] Create method

```
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PersonRodneCislo, FirstName, LastName, Street, City, PSC, PhoneNumber, SecondaryStreet, SecondaryCity, SecondaryPSC")]Person person,
                               [Bind(Include = "InsuranceNumber,Premium,PaymentFrequency,AnnualDate,BeginDate,EndDate,ProductType,PersonRodneCislo")] Insurance insurance,
                               [Bind(Include = "Ico,Street,City,PSC")] Firm firm)
    {
        try
        {
            ViewBag.ProductType = new SelectList(db.Product, "ProductType", "ProductName");
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firm.Ico.ToString()) && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(person.PersonRodneCislo.ToString()))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Ico", "Vložte prosím IČO nebo rodné číslo");
                }
                if (!(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firm.Ico.ToString())))
                {
                    insurance.PersonRodneCislo = person.PersonRodneCislo;              
                    if (!(db.Person.Any(x => x.PersonRodneCislo == person.PersonRodneCislo)))
                    {
                        db.Person.Add(person);
                        db.Insurance.Add(insurance);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        db.Insurance.Add(insurance);
                    }
                }
                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(person.PersonRodneCislo.ToString()))
                {
                    insurance.Ico = firm.Ico;               
                    if (!(db.Firm.Any(x => x.Ico == firm.Ico)))
                    {
                        db.Firm.Add(firm);
                        db.Insurance.Add(insurance);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        db.Insurance.Add(insurance);
                    }
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View(insurance);
        }
    }
```

Comment: check this two post :- http://ciintelligence.blogspot.hk/2013/03/dynamic-conditional-validation-using.html , http://foolproof.codeplex.com/

Comment: its not what i am looking for, problem is with [Key] definition for my PK in tables, its automatically also [Required] and i have to bypass somehow that definition for my property if PersonRodneCislo or Ico is filled in my form but i have no clue how it may be done

Comment: In your case , if you create a partial class for entity meta data class and make it as a normal field , it may work. above two links for validating one property using another one value .i thought you need to validate one value using another. sorry my mistake .